# Interceptar todas a requisições HTTP do angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http

Estou buscando uma forma de interceptar todas as requisições HTTP feitas pelo angular e adicionar alguns *headers*. Nas versões anteriores ao `angular2 RC5` (antes do `NgModule`) era dessa forma, por exemplo:

```ts
class MyOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    Authorization: string = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('tokenName');
}

bootstrap(AppComponent,
    [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyOptions },
    appRouterProviders,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Atualmente estou na versão `2.0 final` e conforme [pesquisa sobre como isso seria implementado nesta versão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249396/2290538), seria algo similar a isso:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyOptions }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

@Injectable()
export class MyOptions extends RequestOptions {
  constructor() { super({method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: new Headers()}); }
}
```

Que apresenta o seguinte erro: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of null`. Como pode ser visto [neste exemplo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yLyG16gDs6et6LkneVaC?p=preview).

> Obs: A implementação de `MyOptions` é a mesma de [`BaseRequestOptions`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L182-L185), copiei pois se utilizar `BaseRequestOptions` em `{ provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions}`, tudo funciona, como pode ser observado [neste exemplo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1gjgwdLt0RbXAqOSD8lh?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma classe de interceptação:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            req = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('NOME', 'VALOR') //setar os headers que você quer
            });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

E no app.module.ts, adicione o seguinte objeto na property providers:

```
{
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: RequestInterceptor,
   multi: true
}
```

Dessa forma todas as requisições feitas passarão por esse interceptador.

[Documentação do Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)